# 'hector_trajectory_server' not found

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am unable to find the hector_trajectory_server package in the /opt/ros/melodic/share/ path. And when I run :

```
rosrun hector_trajectory_server hector_trajectory_server
```

I get the error :

```
[rospack] Error: package 'hector_trajectory_server' not found
```

Is there a way to install this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385833/%27hector_trajectory_server%27-not-found/) by [k2108](https://answers.ros.org/users/30550/k2108/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. You can install it with the command: `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-hector-trajectory-server`.

---

Originally posted by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) with karma: 146 on 2021-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1